# stable drools-guvnor version

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

Can any one please tell me which version of drools-guvnor is more stabled than latest ?

I am currently using 5.3.0 , every time it is getting corrupted .I thought it was a war problem .

please give me some inputs on this .

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 5.5.0.Final version and it works well.

As this is a tool that changes a lot, I'd like to use the 6 version as soon as possible. But at this moment, with 5.5.0 I can do all that I need.

Best regards, Jesús.